# Python TKMACOSX Button Anchor going from center

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using tkmaxosx (MacOS, Pycharm 2020.2.3, Python 3.8) to place buttons in a Python application. I want the button text to work off the top left corner of the button, so I set "anchor=NW".

The problem is, the declared point is using the center point of the button as a fixed reference point. Here is the code:

`foo=Button(foowin, text='Test Text', anchor=NW, height=18, width=145, bg='SystemButtonFace', command=lambda rn=i: FooCommand(variables))`

This is the results, showing different anchors:
[Showing NW, E, W, SE anchors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geb8W.jpg)

Comment: The code doesn't match the image - that code would produce an *enormous* button (18 lines tall, 145 characters wide).  The `height`/`width` options are only interpreted in pixels (which would match the size of the buttons in the image) if you specified an `image` option; additionally you'd have to specify `compound` so that the text is still visible.  So I'm unable to even start trying to duplicate your reported problem.

Comment: This is in the Mac environment, so it's pixels.

Comment: It is an issue with the button itself, it'll fix if you won't set fixed size (width, height) of the button.

Comment: @jasonharper: You are right, but it is a tkmacosx Button which takes height and width in pixels for both text and image.

Comment: @Saad, Nope. Removing height and width attributes still gives the same result, then gives a whole bunch of uneven buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor issue with tkmacosx Button has been ***fixed in version tkmacosx-0.1.6.*** You can upgrade it with

```sh
pip install tkmacosx --upgrade
```